# Kubernetes DNS resolving troubles with Amazon RDS hosts

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, amazon-rds

I have an Flask + SQLAlchemy deployed in Kubernetes, using Amazon AWS as cloud provider (Amazon EC2 machines) with a PostgreSQL RDS.

Sometimes an excetion arises when a request is performed:

`psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "xxx.yyy.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known`

The Amazon RDS instance is located at the same VPC that the Kubernetes cluster, so DNS resolutions must turn into internal IP within the VPC.

I've tried to use Kubernetes `kube-dns` built-in *stubDomains* forcing to resolve `*.rds.amazonaws.com` DNS requests through VPC DNS resolver (in my case 10.0.0.2) but the exception keeps arising.

Does anybody have an idea of what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem

Comment: I have seen that on our flannel backed cluster when the machines are under high CPU load. Also, as a for your consideration, I have never had to alter the `kube-dns` settings, since it will resolve `.cluster.local` names, and then delegate to the EC2 `resolv.conf` as expected. Have you tried altering the Pod's [dnsConfig](https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#poddnsconfig-v1-core)?